# How to replace a space exactly by "\_" in java String?

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I have a string with space and I want that space replace by `"\_"`
. For example here is my code

```
String example = "Bill Gates";
example = example.replaceAll(" ","\\_");
```

And the result of example is: "Bill_Gates" not "Bill\_Gates". When I try to do like this

```
String example = "Bill Gates";
example = example.replaceAll(" ","\\\\_");
```

The result of example is: "Bill\\_Gates" not "Bill\_Gates"

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298982/how-can-i-replace-with-in-java-string

Comment: use replace, `example.replace(" ","\\_");`

Comment: @Leo you want single backslash?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, I justs want a single backslash with an underscore

Comment: then a simple replace would be enough. Try my code..

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `replaceAll(" ","\\\\_")` instead of `replaceAll(" ","\\_")`. Because '\\' is a literal. It will be compiled as '\' single slash. When you pass this to `replaceall` method. It will take first slash as escaping character for "_". If you look inside `replaceall` method

```
    while (cursor < replacement.length()) {
        char nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
        if (nextChar == '\\') {
            cursor++;
            if (cursor == replacement.length())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "character to be escaped is missing");
            nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
            result.append(nextChar);
            cursor++;
```

When it finds a single slash it will replace next character of that slash. So you have to input "\\\\_" to replace method. Then it will be processed as "\\_". Method will look first slash and replace second slash. Then it will replace underscore.

Comment: Thank for your detailed explaination. I want to vote you up but my reputation is not enough yet

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String example = "Bill Gates";
example = example.replaceAll(" ","\\\\_");   
System.out.println(example);
```

Comment: Yes this correct, I did it right but thought it wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "Bill Gates";
        example = example.replaceAll(" ", "\\\\_");
        System.out.println(example);
    }
```

**output**

```
Bill\_Gates
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur, I do debug so I don't see how it renders. On the live debug I saw 2 backslashes so I thought it's not correct

Comment: Sorry I want to vote up but my reputation is not enough :( its just 10 now, I need 15 to vote you guys up